# insert a row after payment with paypal and IPN

Tags: php, mysql, paypal, paypal-ipn

it's a simple question no code needed, I'm usign IPN and paypal and it's working fine, what i want to do and i can't seem to find the way to it's getting information from a table to insert it into an other from the IPN file.Let me explain bettet with an example:

I click the button , go to the paypal page, I pay, the IPN file gets called, the payment_status is completed, good, now i want to get data from a table where the ID of a row in that table is = to the user that's logged in and then get that information to insert it into another table.This from the IPN.php file

```
if($payment_status=='Completed')
{$query="select * from table where id=$_SESSION['login']"}
```

well this..doesn't work

Comment: where id={$_SESSION['login']}

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of login and make sure it is what you expect. My first impression is that that variable is incorrect, however the question is vague enough I can't really answer. :(

Comment: Yeah sorry i dont really know what to add to the question is as simple as I'm asking it,I just want to do a query in the IPN.php file when the payment_status is completed ..the query must have a where condition with the $_SESSION information